# what would be the hook called for bulk order status (woocommerce)?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i want to call my ***custom function*** on ***Bulk order status changed***, to add some additional functionality.
for that  i tried following hooks but nothing work..

```
add_action( 'admin_action_woocommerce_order_status', 'bulk_order_my_function' ); 
add_action( 'admin_action_woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'bulk_order_my_function' ); 
add_action( 'admin_action_wc_processing', 'bulk_order_my_function' ); 
add_action( 'admin_action_woocommerce_processing', 'bulk_order_my_function' );
```

i am more interested in **general order status hook for bulk order update** instead of creating separate function for each status..
**i.e:** so in  my one function **bases on IF/ELSE** condition i can put my logic.

*Would be grateful if anyone can help?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i downloaded the whole woocommerce package and find the string ***bulk*** in the woocommerce folder and certainly i found the hook in the below mentioned file:

> \woocommerce\includes\admin\list-tables\abstract-class-wc-admin-list-table.php

hook we can use is

```
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'bulk_order_stock_update', 10, 3 );
```

function will be some thing like following

```
function bulk_order_stock_update($redirect_to, $action, $ids) {
if ( false !== strpos( $action, 'mark_' ) ) {
        $new_status     = substr( $action, 5 ); // Get the status name from action.
        $report_action  = 'marked_' . $new_status;
        
        //place your some condition here....
   }
}
```